# Assign state to dynamically rendered component using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table with players that is loaded in from an API call and rendered using a map function. The last column of the table contains a delete button. When clicking the delete button, I would like to disable all the other delete buttons until the delete call is completed.

Here is the function that performs the API call to get the players.

```
    loadPlayers() {
        const { cookies } = this.props;
        const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(this.state.access_token);

        axios.get(
            configVars.apiUrl + 'team/get-team',
            { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } }
        ).then(response => {
            var teamArray = response.data;

            //Information gotten
            this.setState({
                teamArray: teamArray,
            });

        }).catch((error) => {
            //Error, remove the access token from cookies and redirect home.
            cookies.remove('access_token');
            this.props.history.push("/");

        });
    }
}
```

Mapping and rendering is done like this:

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
    <Table size="small">
        <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Tier</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Value</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Delete</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        {this.state.teamArray.map((player, i) => {
            return <TableBody key={i}>
                <TableRow key={i}>
                    <TableCell align="left">{player.full_name}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{player.tier}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{player.value}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">
                        <IconButton disabled={this.state.deleteDisable}
                            onClick={() => {this.handleDelete(player.id)}} >
                            <DeleteIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableBody>;
        })}
    </Table>
</Grid>
```

Inside the `handleDelete` function I start by setting `deleteDisabled`in the state to true. However, this has no effect since disabled is set to false once the table is loaded and never changed after.

How do I make sure `this.state.deleteDisable` is passed to the button as a variable instead of assigned once?

Comment: you should store the result of the response into the state, not array of react elements

Comment: Thanks for your response, I updated my question and I agree the code looks more organized this way. Unfortunately, it still doesn't change the state of the buttons when clicking one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the players into the `state`, then in the `render` method you can display the `table`

```
function loadPlayer() {
    const { cookies } = this.props;
    const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(this.state.access_token);

    axios.get(
        configVars.apiUrl + 'team/get-team',
        { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } }
    )
    .then(response => this.setState({players: response.data})})
    .catch((error) => {
        // Error ....
    });
}

render() {
   return (
   ...
   {
     this.state.players((player, i) => (
     <TableBody key={i}>
       <TableRow>
         <TableCell align="left">{player.full_name}</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="right">{player.tier}</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="right">{player.value}</TableCell>
         <TableCell align="right">
           <IconButton disabled={this.state.deleteDisabled}
                       onClick={() => {this.handleDelete(player.id)}} >
             <DeleteIcon />
           </IconButton>
         </TableCell>
       </TableRow>
     </TableBody>
   )}
   ...
   );
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot! Code looks a lot cleaner this way as well.